# Texture or materials not rendering correctly in Cycles but showing in viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

Having issues with rendering image in Cycles. I made a custom texture for my object through an tutorial and messing around with the nodes. But now I noticed that when I try to render a Image in Cycles that the texture is al deformed and also missing some parts and seperate objects I modeled. Any ideas how to fix this?

https://ibb.co/qJnWcvM
https://ibb.co/H7sYqTs
https://ibb.co/fXw9xYz
https://ibb.co/wY0TYYQ

Comment: can u please provide blend file? are your normals ok? did you try to recalculate outside?

Comment: Please do not put external links in your question. You can edit your question and upload the images directly in there.

Comment: https://easyupload.io/cb6o0i  I have no idea. To be honest I am quite new to blender and have only been using it for a little over a week maybe 2 weeks.

Comment: My answer was quicker than your upload... now that I have the file, I can't reproduce your error - is this the file from which you made the screenshots? Because your file doesn't even have a camera in it to render. When I add a new camera and render it, I don't get the result you showed here.

Comment: i made same experience as Gordon: no camera. Cannot reproduce your error. Please upload exactly that blend file from which you made the screenshots. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, I've put the camera on the wrong side. On the other side the Z-fighting is visible - it is Z-fighting as I already said without the file. You have to make the objects invisible in Render, not only in the Viewport... or delete them. I'll add this to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Z-figthing to me without seeing the file. If you take a look in the *Outliner*, there are objects set to be invisible in the *3D Viewport*, but I guess they are visible in *Render*.

[image: invisible objects]

To get rid of those render artifacts you can either delete the invisible objects if you don't need them anymore, or you can disable them in *Render*. To do that, click on the *Filter* symbol in the *Outliner* window menu and enable the *Disable in Renders* button (the camera symbol).

[image: disable in renders]

Now these camera symbols are shown for each object and collection as well and you can disable the *Render Visibility* by clicking (just like you did with the *Viewport Visibility*).

[image: disabled objects]

Comment: https://easyupload.io/f9wgtk Sorry this is the current file with the camera added like I have now.

Comment: I am still working on the texture and forming the shape right way. But here is also an example of what I am trying to recreate. https://ibb.co/KNtt7Jq  Any sugestions, tips, or ideas how to improve my work are welcome as I am a total beginner at this. I have just been trying to use tutorials to create something of my own but I am still struggeling as you can see.

Comment: Fixed the issue! It was indeed the duplicates that I forgot to turn off that was interfering with the rendering.

Comment: @Blendmoth Please consider accepting so that users can see there is a working solution, read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks I couldn't figure out where either the vote up button or accept answer button was.